# Drupal 7 views filter by dynamic taxonomy term

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-views, drupal-taxonomy

I have a few pages (services), each with it's own taxonomy term.

I would like to add a view to the bottom. It should contain all nodes (references) with the same term as the main node (service).

Could it be done by views?

*Read something about and tried contextual filter with no success. Image is bellow*
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are on the right track. Try changing your validator to "Term Id" instead of "Term Name".

I created a block view with the settings you have (with "Term Id" as the validator) and enabled it on my node pages, and this seemed to work.