# Drupal 7 views filter by node's taxonomy term

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-views, drupal-taxonomy

I have a similar question to my previous one ([Drupal 7 views filter by dynamic taxonomy term](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7362360/drupal-7-views-filter-by-dynamic-taxonomy-term)), it's only the other way round.

I have a "partner" content type, each with it's own taxonomy term. The other content type is a regular page with multiple terms from the "partner" vocabulary. In my regular nodes, I want to include a few of the "partners" in a view block.

The view should filter only those relevant partner nodes (those tagged with one of the regular node's tags).

Could it be done this way? The problem is that I can't get the term names from URL via contextual filters...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

After googling the whole afternoon (and posting it there), I eventually found the answer.

It's based on a tutorial on [scito.ch](http://scito.ch/content/show-related-nodes-block-based-taxonomy-terms-views-3-and-drupal-7) (thanks), with only a few modifications. On the `Content: Has taxonomy term ID (with depth)` filter, be sure to check the `Allow multiple values` checkbox. Also (there's a lot of wrong tuts for that), don't specify anything in the `WHEN THE FILTER VALUE IS AVAILABLE OR A DEFAULT IS PROVIDED`. It's important you specify all those 3 contextual filters.

Hope this helps someone and saves him a sunny afternoon :)